# If the following S is a vector space, are the following U and V subspaces of S?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If the following $S$ a vector space:
$$
S = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} ax^2+bx+c \\d \end{bmatrix}  | \space a,b,c,d \space \in \space \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

Then are the following $U$ and $V$ subspaces of S?
$$
U = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} ex+f \\g \end{bmatrix}  | \space e,f,g \space \in \space \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
$$
V = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} h \\0 \end{bmatrix}  | \space h \space \in \space \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

In my head it makes sense for both to be subspaces of $S$.

$U$ could be the subspace of $S$ where $a = 0$, and $V$ could be a subspace where $a = b = d = 0$, but this does not seem like a correct answer at all to me.

Comment: Why not? Too simple a question?

Comment: Yes, see if you can identify for yourself why you're hesitating. Why "does it not seem like a correct answer at all"??